# Changing magento order status and button action on admin

Tags: magento, adminhtml

I want to change to button actions in the Magento admin orders section, and after looking at a lot of posts on here I can not find an answer that fulfills my question:

Question:
I want to be able to click the print invoice button on the order and have it automatically change to shipped status and when I add shipping to the order with a tracking number and click submit I would like that status to change to shipped.. and I was wondering how this could be done?

In summary:
status changed to shipped - when invoice is printed
status changed to complete - when order is shipped

I assume I would start in editing this section: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php

Answer (score 0):

To change the status of an order the instruction is :

```
 $order->setState('your state', true);
```

Ex. :

```
$order->setState('complete', true);
```

To have what you want you should edit the controller called when printing the invoice or creating the shipment. It's :

/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php in the printAction() method just after the line :

```
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
```

For the printing of invoice and

/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php in the saveAction() method just after the line :

```
 $shipment->register();
```

But editing Controller is the most simple but the worst solution. If you know well Magento and php you could do this through Model or through events.

Best Regards,

Comment: I tried the following:  
1) I went to  
'/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php' and located the line of 'printAction()' method  and just after the line below:  
'$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));'
  
I put this:  
'$order->setState('processing', true);'  
  
When I did that I got this warning when trying to print an invoice from the order screen  

Fatal error: Call to a member function setState() on a non-object in domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php on line 120